# Replacement for mananging SSO settings in Google

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Now that the [Google Admin API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate) has been deprecated as of October 31, 2018 they have listed that there is supposed to be a replacement API call released on the same date.  However, I can't seem to find anything on it.  Most specifically, I want to be able to update SSO settings in the admin console.  Anyone know if this was released and where it may be now?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/10/gdata-admin-settings-api-shutdown-update.html) post from October:

```
Single Sign-on (SSO) settings and Gateway and routing settings features not yet shutting down
```